# Gulp TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I have i problem with gulp-ruby-sass. When i try to run the *watch* task and change some .sass files it occurs error:

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
```

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
})
```

I used gulp-slash but it don't works.

Comment: You're requiring `gulp-watch` but not using it. Are you sure this is the exact gulpfile that the problem occurs with?

Comment: it is on windows. why you say that i am not using gulp-watch?        `gulp.task('watch', function() {
     gulp.watch('./sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
})` there is my task for watch. when i comment the line `.pipe(sass())` the problem is absent, but i have another problem - my sass don't compile to css :)

Comment: `gulp-watch` is a separate library. `gulp.watch` is part of gulp. Are you using the latest versions of all modules?

Comment: yes, i am. and i don't understand what happens

Comment: What version of `gulp-ruby-sass` do you have?

Comment: `"gulp-ruby-sass": "^1.0.0-alpha"`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

With the [syntax changes](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/tree/rw/1.0#usage) in **gulp-ruby-sass** starting from 1.0.0-alpha, you'll need to use `gulp-ruby-sass()` instead of `gulp.src()` to compile your Sass from a file or directory.

If you try to use the original syntax with newer or latest versions, you may encounter the following error:

`TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings`

For example, the original syntax in 0.7.x and earlier using gulp.src(), now deprecated:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

// gulp-ruby-sass: 0.7.1
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('path/to/scss')
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/css'));
});
```

The new syntax introduced in 1.x using gulp-ruby-sass() as a gulp source adapter:

```js
// gulp-ruby-sass: 1.x
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('path/to/scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/css'));
});
```

Notice the difference in the first line of the return statement.

*Also keep in mind, as of this writing when using gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.0-alpha, globs are not supported yet.*

Comment: Just in case it happened to someone else, keep in mind that **you must have Sass >= 3.4**, according to the same [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/tree/rw/1.0#install).

Comment: Might help someone: File or glob pattern (source/**/*.scss) to compile. Ignores files prefixed with an underscore. **Directory sources are not supported.**

Answer (score 6):

`gulp-ruby-sass` syntax changes in version 1.0.0. See this issue:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/191

New docs are currently here:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/tree/rw/1.0#gulp-ruby-sass-is-a-gulp-source-adapter

This should compile sass files in specified directory:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('sass/')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Comment: Please add this as a comment to the above answer. It's a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off-topic, but in the case of also wanting to use [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps), the various documentation out there is somewhat outdated. To use [rjb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245264/rjb)'s example with sourcemaps, you would thus go

```js
// gulp-ruby-sass: 1.x
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('path/to/scss', { style: 'expanded', sourcemap: true })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/css'));
});
```

Note that the destination arg for sourcemaps, `'./'`, will evaluate to the folder in the line below, `gulp.dest(...)`, effectively here, map-file will end up in `'path/to/css'`.

Credit for this goes to http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/getting-scss-auto-prefixer-and-source-map-to-play-nice/.