# Gulp error on gulp-ruby-sass task

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp

This is the gulpfile in my website project:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),

    sass_path = 'src/style/*.scss';

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  gulp.watch(sass_path, ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {

  gulp.src(sass_path)
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

When I try to run gulp, it break before finish the task 'styles', and give the output:

```
[15:37:00] Starting 'styles'...
[15:37:00] 'styles' errored after 1.92 ms
[15:37:00] TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at module.exports (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:61:15)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/Gulpfile.js:24:9)
    at module.exports (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
    at finish (/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/lab/gulp/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of `gulp-ruby-sass` do you have?

Comment: The current stable version, not the alpha

Comment: Alpha would have explained it. Here's similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140012/gulp-typeerror-arguments-to-path-join-must-be-strings

Answer (score 4):

The sintax of ´gulp-ruby-sass´ changed and now is like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {

  return sass('src/style')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me .