# Gulp - TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be string

Tags: sass, gulp

So I'm trying gulp out but I get this.

> TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be string

What am I missing here?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('scss/*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch'], function() {});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulp TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140012/gulp-typeerror-arguments-to-path-join-must-be-strings)

Comment: I read through that post and changed my gulpfile accordingly before posting but I must have missed something because I still get that error. I can't find a difference between what I have and what the answer is on that post.

Comment: Check gulp-ruby-sass version and the correct syntax.