# ionic build ios fails with "[TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]"

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, cross-platform, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic app on Mac.

I followed the instructions on ionic's website to create a basic app and was able to run it in the browser but when I run "ionic build ios" I get following error. I cannot find a log file or any other error to debug this. How do I go about fixing this?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after lot of looking and searching I figured my npm install was messed up.

Part of my installs were in /usr/local and few of them were in /User/user.name/npm folders. /Users/user.name/npm was set in the npm config prefix.

I had two installs of cordova, one on each folder above. Some how the cordova from /usr/local was getting used to create the project and that was the old version.

To fix the problem, I uninstalled all my global npm installs and pointed my npm config prefix to /usr/local and gave myself execute permission on that folder. Everything is working now.

Here is the video that explains how to do it: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gulp version and gulpfile.js. You may need to remove the calls to gulp.src

See:

[Gulp TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140012/gulp-typeerror-arguments-to-path-join-must-be-strings)

and

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/191

Comment: it was a problem with my npm and nothing to do with Gulp. I did look at that link, thanks for your help.